# JsRender "footer" space

Tags: html, css, jsrender

I'm working with jsrender and i need to use all the space in the page but there is some space in the "footer" that can't be use, i need that the table use the full height

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table style=" height: 100%;margin: 0;background-color: red;">
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make your table full width? Please revise to be more clear. Edit the snippet to show the problem. We can't debug images.

Comment: yes that's what i need, excuse me , i already add the image

Comment: I took the image out, for the reason I mentioned. Make the snippet show the problem, please, so we know what we're debugging.

Comment: in the snippet  the table takes the 100% and it's ok, but when i use jsrender it takes almost the 85% heigh of the page, it's like there is some "footer" that can be use,but is only with the js render, that's what i need to know how to solve

Answer (score 0):

As youre stating in the comments you want the table to take 100% of the available width, just add `width:100%;` to your table. Also you should move your table styles from inline-styles to the css.

I added the neccessary styles in the following snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: in the snippet the table takes the 100% and it's ok, but when i use jsrender it takes almost the 85% heigh of the page, it's like there is some "footer" that can be use,but is only with the js render, that's what i need to know how to solve